# Who is the Supreme of Howicce, from "Deryni Rising?"

Tags: deryni-series

Towards the beginning of *Deryni Rising*, there is a humorous scene where Morgan and Derry must move out of the way of the passing entourage of the "Supreme of Howicce" (then also modestly referred to as "His Loftiness").

I do not remember ever seeing the "Supreme of Howicce" in any other place in the series.

Do we ever find out who he is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the *Codex Derynianus*,

> this self-important *minister premier* of Howicce was customarily
> escorted by an honor guard of xiii fierce Connaiti mercenary warriors,
> all vii feet tall, mailed in bronze and garbed garishly in the gaudy
> green and violet trappings of the United Kingdoms of Howicce and
> Llanadd... the Supreme resides in the curious octagon House at Sirhowy
> in Howicce, with each of its viii sides being painted a different
> colour.

The codex also indicates he only appears or is mentioned in *Deryni Rising*.

Comment: Hi Nezz and welcome to SF&F!! I find this intriguing because one would expect someone with such a 'big' title  to be, say, the king of that country, or a member of the royal family, but the behaviour does not appear at all in character with the personalities of the Howicce royalty we see in The King's Deryni...

Comment: Oh, and I'm Liesel "over there".

Answer (score 6):

I don't have all the short stories to hand, just the ones that were collected in [*Deryni Archives*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?38309) (which is most of them, after all), but in all the published books and *Deryni Archives* there is no further mention in text of the "Supreme of Howicce," and the only other use of "Supreme" as a title I can find is in a wedding ceremony where God is addressed as the "Supreme Witness."  (*The Bishop's Heir*)

There is a listing for the "Supreme of Howicce" in the "Index of Characters" included as Appendix I in *High Deryni*, but it doesn't provide any further information:

> SUPREME of Howicce, The representative of the United Kingdoms of Howicce and
> Llannedd at Kelson's coronation, escorted by Connaiti mercenaries [I].

So what appears in *Deryni Rising* is exactly as much as we ever know about the "Supreme of Howicce."

Comment: Thank you.  Very good answer, but information from the Codex, to which I don't have access -- I had to accept that one!